# orphanedRowAction on TypeORM with migrations

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am using the new feature orphanedRowAction on TypeORM version 0.2.30 (2021-01-12):

```
@ChildEntity('business')
export default class BusinessGeolocation extends Geolocation {
  @ManyToOne(
    type => Business, business => business.geolocations, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      orphanedRowAction: "delete" // NEW
    })
  business!: Business;
}
```

Which works fine ( I can delete orphan rows) when I start my app using synchronized = true . However, I can't delete orphan rows with migrations=true. I could not find what changes on sql expression, when I start my app with migration instead.

```
Error: Run: error code 19: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

query failed:  DELETE FROM "forms" WHERE "formId" = ? -- PARAMETERS: [1]
```

What changes on sql expression when orphanedRowAction: "delete" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out for some reason I could not get the correct sql expression output, then I reset all my data, and it seems the main change for those who will create tables using migrations is this one:

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION ---> ON DELETE ON CASCADE
```